# EXCEL / VBA - function #VALUE error in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

(I want to calculate the number of possible ways of getting 'sum' out of 'n' dice throws (dices have 'k' faces from 1..k).)

**When i want to use this function in an excel spreadsheet, I get a #VALUE error no matter what inputs i try.**
I have other functions in the same module, used in the same sheet that work fine\

```vb
Function how_many_ways(n, k, sum)
    If n = 0 Then
        If sum = 0 Then
            how_many_ways = 1
        Else
            how_many_ways = 0
        End If
    End If
    
    If sum < 0 Or k * n < sum Or n > sum Then
        how_many_ways = 0
    End If
    
    res = 0
    For i = 1 To k
        res = res + how_many_ways(n - 1, k, sum - i)
    Next i
    
    how_many_ways = res
    
End Function
```

Comment: How does it jump out of the loop?  If `k` = 1 then it will enter the loop, recall the function with `k` still equaling 1 and then enter the loop again...... and so on.  Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (Tools ~ Options ~ Editor ~ Require Variable Declaration`).  You've not declared any of your variables.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't the function just return if n = 0 as in the if at the top, so in the For loop when n-1 reaches 0 it should just continue because the recursively called function just returns instantly?

Comment: Also could you tell me why do I need to explicitly declare my variables? Aren't they just local variables?

Comment: Returns don't stop the code from running you would need an `exit function` or elseifs like in Axuary's answer. Declaring variables is good practice, there is no reason for them to be variants and `option explicit` will catch typos.

Comment: Thank you it solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always runs the for loop so it recurs infinitely.  Try this.

```
Function how_many_ways(n, k, sum)
    If n = 0 Then
        If sum = 0 Then
            how_many_ways = 1
        Else
            how_many_ways = 0
        End If
    ElseIf sum < 0 Or k * n < sum Or n > sum Then
        how_many_ways = 0
    Else
       res = 0
       For i = 1 To k
           res = res + how_many_ways(n - 1, k, sum - i)
       Next i
       how_many_ways = res
    End If
End Function
```